# How to convert month and day to date format?

Tags: r, datetime

I want to change this data format:

```
# A tibble: 366 x 4
# Groups:   year, month [?]
    year month   day mean_per_day
   <int> <dbl> <int>        <dbl>
 1  2013     1     1        11.6 
 2  2013     1     2        13.9 
 3  2013     1     3        11.0 
 4  2013     1     4         8.95
 5  2013     1     5         5.73
 6  2013     1     6         7.15
 7  2013     1     7         5.42
 8  2013     1     8         2.55
 9  2013     1     9         2.28
10  2013     1    10         2.84
# ... with 356 more rows
```

to a column with date format corresponding to every row? (for example for row 5 I want 2013-jan-5)
or is there a way to calculate the number of day of a year? (for example Feb, 5th is 36th day of year)
Also how do you recommend to plot "mean_per_day" variable for every day? (using ggplot2)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also please ask one question at a time. Here you are mixing defining datetime by pasting columns with ploting means.